# Selecting date in celander is giving me previous date using Vurig-Calendar Library in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nscalendar

I have downloaded this library https://github.com/TjeerdVurig/Vurig-Calendar. Now the problem which I'm facing, for example if I select 25th feb 2013 it is printing 24th Feb 2013. I Can't find anything in code. Is it because of time zone or something that is not related with coding?? 
Please Advise

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have problems with time zone and it can be solved by adding this line of code:

[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];

**Update**

1. [Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12184454/converting-a-date-by-string-format-to-nsdate-result-one-day-before-string-date)
2. [Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318603/nsdate-is-not-converting-correctly-using-nsdateformatter)
3. [Question 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11273001/nsdateformatter-datefromstring-returns-incorrect-date)

Comment: Thanks for the help but even after paste this code I'm still having same problem.

Comment: just play with GMT it may help you

Comment: tried all the above suggestions still its not working..Thanks though

Comment: Thanks mate all three links were really helpful and to the point. learned a lot thanks.

Comment: You were right at first place instead of NSDateFormatter's TimeZone I just need to change NSDateComponents timeZone.[components setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]]; and not its working fine.Thanks once again

Answer (score 1):

That is very easy to do. In your `VRGCalendarView.m` go to method

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    int firstWeekDay = [self.currentMonth firstWeekDayInMonth]-1;
}
```

Change this to :

```
int firstWeekDay = [self.currentMonth firstWeekDayInMonth];
```

and

```
int selectedDateBlock = ([selectedDate day]-1)+firstWeekDay;
```

change this one to

```
int selectedDateBlock = ([selectedDate day]-2)+firstWeekDay;
```